# restart fuse after editing fuse.conf

Tags: fuse

I'm setting up fuse so I can work with the mtp system on my galaxy nexus. And I'm going through a tutorial which tells me to restart my computer after editing `fuse.conf` `user_allow_other`.

But I simply don't believe that I actually have to restart =P

Is there a way to get the system to re-read the fuse.conf file without restarting?

Comment: Reload the fuse kernel module.

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to do anything. The file is read whenever you try to mount something.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that your user has access to `/etc/fuse.conf` by adding it to the group `fuse`:

```
addgroup $(id -u) fuse
```

Then login again to reload the `/etc/group` file.